# iOS change programmatically setup font

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift4

I change programmatically UILabel (from the storyboard) font (custom font) depends on various size class in
`traitCollectionDidChange` in `UIViewController`.
When view appears on screen my label has storyboard setup font not mine. By KVO i observe `label.font` and saw that runtime setup systemFont after my setup. And it's happening after viewWillAppear. I fix this by changing font in `MyLabel Class` in `override func layoutSubviews`. But still don't understand what was happening in `viewController` and why runtime change font? Will be very thankful for detail explanation

Comment: If you want to change font of UILabel which is created by `UIStoryboard` or `xib`, `awakeFromNib()` is the method you should use.

Comment: @Ryan in awakeFromNib() your traitcollection size class and interfaceidiom still unspecified